# CakePHP declaring Model Associations within a Behavior

Tags: cakephp

I am building a "Notification" system and am working on a Notifiable Behavior which I aim to attach to various objects -- Posts, Transactions, Friends, etc.  While I had this working using manual associations declared within each model, I was hoping that I could have each model `$actsAs Notifiable` and dynamically declare the model associations from within there.  This would save a fair amount of lines of code and make it a little more expandable in the future.

Model structure is pretty much this as an example:

`Post`

```
id
post_content
```

`Notification`

```
id
type
parent_id
```

The aim is to associate these models (and any other 'Notifiable' model) by saying: `Post hasMany Notification WHERE Notification.type = 'Post' AND Notification.parent_id = Post.id` or something to that effect.

I'm running into problems.  The first is that the SQL is returning an error that the associated columns are not found in the model referenced.  The second is that my `contains()` function is not able to find the associated models either.

`Post Model`

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post'
    public $actsAs = array( 'Containable', 'Notifiable' );
}
```

`Notifiable Behavior`

```
    public function setup(Model $Model, $settings = array()) {
    if (!isset($this->settings[$Model->alias])) {
        $this->settings[$Model->alias] = array();
    }
    $this->settings[$Model->alias] = array_merge($this->settings[$Model->alias], $settings);
    $Model->bindModel( array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'Notification' => array(
                'className' => 'Notification',
                'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Notification.type = "' . $Model->name . '"',
                ),
                'dependent' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ), false );
    $Model->Notification->bindModel( array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            $Model->name => array(
                'className' => $Model->name,
                'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Notification.type = "' . $Model->name . '"',
                )
            )
        )
    ), false );
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way and/or is my understanding of what Behaviors are for a little skewed?  I know that bindModel will work until the end of the request with `false` set as the second variable.  However, are these associations not accessible globally when declared within a behavior?

In other words, if I have a `NotificationsController` which has:

```
'contain' => array( 
    'Friend',
    'Post',
    'Transaction'
)
```

Should this work if those Models `actAs` Notifiable?  Like I said, I can get it to work if I manually declare the model associations within each model.  But this becomes cumbersome in the case of the `Notification` model, which I must then declare for every single `Notifiable` model:

```
$belongsTo = array(
    'ModelAlias' => array(
        'className' => 'Model',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Notification.type' => 'Model'
        )
    )
);
```

So in the terms of scalability, I'd prefer not to have to continue to manually declare these associations every time I add a new model that I decide should be notifiable.

I hope I've explained that well enough.  I'm still getting the grip of CakePHP so please let me know if I'm going about this all wrong.

Thanks!

EDIT:

To simplify the description of the problem and error:

I have `Transaction actsAs Notifiable` .  The code for my `Notifiable` behavior is still as it appears above.  The intended function is to declare `Transaction hasMany Notification` and `Notification belongsTo Transaction`.  In my `TransactionsController` I attempt to Paginate the Notifications model using the following:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Transaction',
    )
    'limit' => 5,
);
$this->notifications = $this->Paginator->paginate( 'Notification' );
$this->set( 'notifications', $this->notifications );
```

And what I receive is a set of `Notification` models that do not have any of their associated `belongsTo` Models attached, along with the error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Transaction [APP/View/Notifications/index.ctp, line 10]
```

The same occurs with every `Notifiable` Model that I have, unless I explicitly instantiate them elsewhere in the app and/or attach it manually to the `Notifiable` model.

I feel it may have to do with the declaration of `$Model->Notification->belongsTo`, which assigns the Notification explicitly to the Model, rather than declaring the Notification model itself as having that association, if that makes any sense at all.

Does that help clarify the problem?

**EDIT:**

I have found that if I explicitly call `$this->Transaction->create();` (or `create()` on any other `Notifiable` model), within my `NotificationsController` before I run `$this->paginate();`, the association is returned correctly.  This, however kind of defeats the purpose of the automation I am trying to create if I have to manually create/declare each `Notifiable` object before running the query.

Comment: It should work for me and that is the right way to use the behaviors. I just would change your conditions in `'conditions' => array('Notification.type' => $Model->name)` but I don't think that this is the problem. Can you be more specific and edit your question inserting the errors you get?

Comment: Thanks.  I will update with a little more info tonight.  As a follow-up question, which may illustrate the problem a little better: are the associations made within a behavior this way, using `bindModel` available to other Models?  If I define `Post hasMany Notification` in the `NotifiableBehavior`, then if `User hasMany Post`, if I do `User->find()` should the `Post` models return their associated `Notifications` as well automatically?  It seems this was not happening.  Thank you again, and I will update as soon as I can.

Comment: yes it should but it depends on how you set recursive

Comment: Thank you again for the help so far.  I have edited the original post to include the error I am receiving as well as the circumstances in which I receive it.  I feel like I know what the problem may be, but I do not know of a way to fix it.

Comment: not `$this->Paginator->paginate( 'Notification' );` but simply` $this->paginate( 'Notification' );` Or if you are in NotificationsController just `$this->paginate()`

Comment: Still a no-go.  I tried both `$this->paginate( 'Notification')` and `$this->paginate()` with the same error:  `Model "Notification" is not associated with model "Transaction"`.  If I `debug( $this->Notification->belongsTo )` before my `contain()` it does not show any of the associated models.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @arilia , I have added another EDIT to my original post.  If I declare the associated models manually before I paginate(), it appears to work, however this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Ok, now I understand: you are in your NotificationsController. But cthe associations you need are set in the other models, not in Notification Model. Cake doesn't load models that are not used so Post Model is not loaded and association with Notification is not created. I think that all you can do is tell notificationsControllers that it uses Post Model using `uses`

Comment: That's a simple enough explanation.  However, I do list these models in the `NotificationsController` `$uses` array.  Nevertheless, it keeps telling me that `Model "Notification" is not associated with model "Transaction" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]` (or "Post" or any other Notifiable model), unless I explicitly write `$this->Transaction->create();` before my pagination.  Maybe the behaviors aren't referenced unless the model is explicitly instantiated.  If that's the case, I guess I'll just have to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 1):

I have found when I declare associations like this in a behavior it seems to work more "automatically" like you wanted. Ran into the same problem as you recently. I think this might be a fix. Try it out!

```
public function setup(Model $Model, $settings = array()) {
    $Model->hasMany = array(
      //set associations here
    );
}
```